# Image of the map $Spec\mathcal O_{X,x}$ to $X$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let X be scheme and $x\in X$. Can someone help to show that the image of the morphism $Spec \mathcal O_{X,x}\rightarrow X$ is the set of points of X that specialize to x.

And how does it follow form the above fact that: Set of prime divisors of X containing x and set of prime divisors of $Spec \mathcal O_{X,x}$ are in one-to-one correspondence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the affine case, this is the well-known classification of prime ideals of a localization of a commutative ring at a prime ideal. In the general case, glue everything.

Comment: I understand what you want to say. Can you give a more straight forward clear proof?

Comment: Can you complete it yourself? If you are too lazy or it's too hard, look it up in EGA I.

Comment: @Mark: Is it true that if y specializes x then there is an open affine subset of X containing both x and y?

Comment: Yes, it is true: if $y$ specialises to $x$, **any** open neighbourhood of $x$ in $X$ (affine or not!) will contain $y$. [And who is this mysterious Mark ? :-)]

Comment: It's (EGA, I, 2.4) if you want: http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=PMIHES_1960__4__5_0